# How do I get/review each record in my known hosts

Tags: openssh

I recently have had "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED", I started digging to double check whats happening.
I wanted to review all entries which I have as I just think it might be some overlap has happened from different networks or just IP changed because of new DHCP lease.
How do I review each entry? I need to know IP/DNS name for each entry and preferably thumbprint. I think I can get thumbprint by running `ssh-keygen -F host-ip-or-address -l`.

Comment: Check your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. Find the line with the host/IP that has changed, delete the line, save the file, and connect as usual. I run into this with EC2 instances often as they’re ephemeral.

Comment: @matigo nothing has changed as I have not yet removed anythingfrom my ~/,ssh/known_hosts. I have 20+ lines and they all not clear for which hosts.